# Run in asp.net app javascript code before response window download

Tags: javascript, asp.net, response, httpresponse

I have developped a page that, when a user clicks a button, after a query lets download a xlsx.
The query could take a couple of seconds so i want to hide the button during the operation.

I know that it is normally an easy operation, via js on the button:

```
<asp:ImageButton id="Bt" OnClientClick=" this.style.display = 'none';  />
```

and server side when the script ends:

```
Bt.Style.Add("display", "inline");
```

But in order to make the xslx i use this code:

```
response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=name.xlsx");
response.TransmitFile(file_path);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Clearting the response context does not allow me to run other javascript code in the script (it just does not work), so I do not know how I can set the visibility of the button to inline.

Comment: you're right it won't work server-side because you're providing an entirely different response to the client - sending a file, not refreshing the page. But equally client-side there's no way to detect when the download has finished (for essentially the same reason - it's a totally separate request outside of your actual page context). Lots of people have tried to solve this: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=js%20detect%20end%20of%20file%20download As you can see there are no reliable or simple solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADyson's suggestion in the comment is right. There is no cosy solution to solve this problem.
By the way, I did a trick to solve this, it's kind of lame but it's easy and it works. If it could be usefull to someone i post it anyway.

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch
{
   ...
}
finally
{
  script = "document.getElementById('Bt').style.display = 'inline';";
  if(add_click)
     script += "document.getElementById('Bt_Download_Hidden').click();";

 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "alert", @"
     <script type=""text/javascript"">
       " + script + @"
     </script>");
        }
```

In the button were before i did all the work i just prepare the xlsx and store the result path in an session variable.
As you see in the finally clause i run a script that always sets the visibility of the button back to inline and in the end, if it goes all fine, it clicks an hidden button. In this second button i put the code to download the file.
So i force the flushing operation to be the last one.